HP Elitebook 840: reboot after install says OS not found
HP Elitebook 840: reboot after install says OS not found
I have tried UEFI mode, and "Legacy" mode......same result.
Ubuntu runs fine from USB pendrive.
I can SEE the partitions and Linux files on the disk (SSD)
It ran Win 10 before, but I erased it....only Ubunto on the drive.
I will be thankful for any tips on how to fix this
Rolf

never had a problem with an HP Elitebook (installed on two systems so far). However, saw a video yesterday which suggested on HP pressing Esc to get to the BIOS setup then Advanced -> Device Boot Conf -> Legacy Support Enable and Secure Boot Disable option. Personally, I didn't touch any of the settings (bar selecting the USB as the first boot option).

HP typically requires you to go into system settings and change boot order there. If installed in UEFI boot mode, you need to keep UEFI boot on. Screenshot of HP's UEFI settings change of boot order
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490924&page=2 &
https://www.phoronix.com/news/HP-BIOSCFG-For-Linux-6.6

Can you boot from the BIOS boot menu? Turn on or restart the computer, and when the HP logo appears, press f9 to enter the Boot Device Options menu. From the user guide http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05920079.pdf

How you write an ISO to your install media can adversely impact the write of boot details; though in most cases it can be detected on the summary screen prior to actual install. We've been given no specifics; no clue as to Ubuntu product, release of that product, ISO choice (if available) or how it was written to media (was it a simple clone that'll work on all, or reformat via options so it'll only work on specific devices?)  Please be specific with details.
